# textview content that leads to an automatic action

Tags: android, textview, listener

I am using a source code of a Speech-To-Text app (using Google Voice).

I would like to add a code that does the following:

Whenever the content of a TextView shows value X, it leads to an automatic action. And whenever it displays value Y, it leads to a different action.

For instance, the TextView content is read aloud, or the background colour is changed, etc. Not a *setOnClickListener*, but an automatic action. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the `TextWatcher` that might give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's so simple check this out:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String text = charSequence.toString();
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            //Do your action
        }else if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
            //Do your action
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that works nicely! I've experimented with textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); and textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); and that works fine. However, do you know how I can let Android read out the content as the action?

Comment: @Etsenmaker You're welcome you can also upvote an answer by pressing the up arrow on the left side :). "read out the content as the action" I'm not sure what you mean by that ? Can you clearify

Comment: By "read out" I mean Text To Speech. I have the source code of a TTS app, but I would like new TextView content to be read out (TTS) automatically (not by means of an onClickListener). Perhpaps your TextWatcher can be used for that somehow? PS I wanted to upvote your reply but I'm afraid my account is too junior still... ;)

Comment: so you write a thing in editText and you want it to be readout am I right?Okay so you need to know when the user ends well.Take it 5 seconds.So the last time it was written to editText by TTS was 5 seconds ago read it out.Otherwise wait for more input.If you don't know how to do this.You should ask another question and put the link here in the comments and Then I'll go there to help you the rest of the way.Because it's a different topic.

Comment: (Ideally, I'd like a TextView to be read out, not an EditText.) Thanks so much for your help Steve! Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736693/textview-content-read-aloud-without-setonclicklistener-automatic-text-to-speech