# TextView content read aloud without setOnClickListener (Automatic Text-To-Speech)

Tags: android, listener, voice

I am using the source code of a Text-To-Speech app. I would like the content of a TextView to be read aloud automatically (i.e. without the use of *setOnClickListener*). Does anyone know how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the final result, and it works:

```
mVoiceOutputTv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String text = charSequence.toString();
        if (text.contains(text)) {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toSpeak = mVoiceOutputTv.getText().toString();
                    textToSpeech.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable editable) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this code.Let me know if it doesn't work:

```
Timer timer;

textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do your reading out here
            }
        },1000);//1000 milliseconds change it to whatever interval you want.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't... :) I've posted what I've got so far in the MainActivity.

Comment: This works fine so far, but I want to write a code that reads (TTS) the content of a TextView automatically (i.e. without the use of a button). That is something I haven't got yet. Do you know how to add/write that?

Comment: @Etsenmaker I meant can you state what's wrong with my code?You tested it.So what happends that doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry. Your code works in that it contains no errors, but it does not realise an automatic TTS action.

Comment: @Etsenmaker Well //Do your reading here I put a comment for you there and you didn't do anything in your code.Put your reading there.

Comment: Both: 
                    public void run() {
                        mVoiceInputTv1.getText();

And:
                    public void run() {
                        String toSpeak = "hello";

Do not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean toSpeak doesn't work?Well it's a string just use your toSpeak = method.mVoiceInputTv1.getText().toString();
textToSpeech1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);